# Drawing on canvas after megapix rendering is reversed

Tags: javascript, iphone, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a page which allows you to browse in an image, then draw on it and save both the original and the annotated version. I am leveraging megapix-image.js and exif.js to help in rendering images from multiple mobile devices properly. It works great, except in certain orientations. For example, a vertical photo taken on an iPhone4s is considered orientation 6 by exif and gets flipped accordingly by megapix-image so it's rendered nicely on the canvas. For some reason, when I draw on it afterward, it seems like the drawing is reversed. Mouse and touch both behave the same way. The coordinates look right to me (meaning they match a working horizontal pic and a non-working vertical pic), as does the canvas height and width when megapix-image.js flips it. This leads me to believe it has something to do with the context, but honestly, I am not really sure. I have a JS fiddle of the part of my work that shows the behavior. Just browse in a vertically taken pic from a mobile device or take a pic in vertical format on a mobile device and use it. I think all will show this same behavior.

The final rendering is done like this:

```
        function RenderImage(file2) {

            if (typeof file2[0].files[0] != 'undefined') {

                EXIF.getData(file2[0].files[0], function () {

                    orientation = EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation");

                    var file = file2[0].files[0];

                    var mpImg = new MegaPixImage(file);



                    var resCanvas1 = document.getElementById('annoCanvas');


                    mpImg.render(resCanvas1, {
                        maxWidth: 700,
                        maxHeight: 700,
                        orientation: orientation
                    });



                });

            }

        }
```

But the full jsfiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/awebster28/Tq3qU/6/

Does anyone have any clues for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by adding another canvas to my html (named "annoCanvas2"). Then, I updated megapix-image.js to include this function, which draws the contents of the new canvas to a fresh one:

```
function drawTwin(sourceCanvas)
 {
  var id = sourceCanvas.id + "2";
  var destCanvas = document.getElementById(id);

  if (destCanvas !== null) {
    var twinCtx = destCanvas.getContext("2d");
     destCanvas.width = sourceCanvas.width;
    destCanvas.height = sourceCanvas.height;

    twinCtx.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, sourceCanvas.width, sourceCanvas.height);
 }
}
```

Then, just after the first is rotated and flipped and rendered, I rendered the resulting canvas to my "twin". Then I had a nice canvas, with my updated image that I could then draw on and also save!

```
var tagName = target.tagName.toLowerCase();
 if (tagName === 'img') {
        target.src = renderImageToDataURL(this.srcImage, opt, doSquash);
 } else if (tagName === 'canvas') {
    renderImageToCanvas(this.srcImage, target, opt, doSquash);

   //------I added this-----------
   drawTwin(target);

}
```

I was glad to have it fixed so I met my deadline, but I am still not sure why I had to do this. If anyone out there can explain it, I'd love to know why.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the lib you are using there is a transformCoordinate function that is used to set the right transform before drawing.
And they don't save/restore the canvas (boooo!!!) so it remains with this transform after-wise.

Solution for you is to do what the lib should do : save the context before the render and restore it after :

```
  function RenderImage(file2) {

              // ... same code ...

              var mpImg = new MegaPixImage(file);

               var eData = EXIF.pretty(this);

               // Render resized image into canvas element.
               var resCanvas1 = document.getElementById('annoCanvas');

               var ctx = resCanvas1.getContext('2d');
               ctx.save(); 
               //setting the orientation flips it
               mpImg.render(resCanvas1, {
                        maxWidth: 700,
                        maxHeight: 700,
                        orientation: orientation
                    });
               ctx.restore();

              //...

        }
```

Comment: I thought they did though...look at renderImageToCanvas in megapix-image.js. They do a save, then a restore after transforming. Are you saying I need to do this again